# PIC18F45J50 UART remappable problem

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, uart, programming

Hello i need help with the Remappable UART communication on pic18f45j50.

so here is my code compiled using Mikroc Pro for pic

```
 //Set Analog pins as digital...
 ADCON1=0X0F;
 ///////////////////////////////

 //Initialize UART2 module with Peripheral Pin Select
 Unlock_IOLOCK();
 PPS_Mapping_NoLock(0, _INPUT, _RX2_DT2);
 PPS_Mapping_NoLock(1, _OUTPUT, _TX2_CK2);
 Lock_IOLOCK();
 delay_ms(100);
 UART_Remappable_Init(9600);
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

 //Initialize UART1 module
 delay_ms(100);
 UART1_Init(9600);
 Delay_ms(300);
 /////////////////////////

 //Infinite Loop...
 while (1) 
 {
     if (UART_Remappable_Data_Ready()==1)
     {
     UART_Remappable_Read_Text(output, "OK", 15);
     UART_Remappable_write_Text(output);
     delay_ms(100);
     }
 }//loop ends......
```

connected the RP0 and RP1 to the usb-uart module. but it seems only tx is working on the microcontroller..

it means only microcontroller can send data but cannot receive data?

BTW.. RP0 and RP1 represent pin 19 and 20 resp.. which is RB0 and RB1 normally.. so is there i'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

> `Set Analog pins as digital...  ADCON1=0X0F;`

Setting analog port pins to digital is done via the A**N**CONx registers, not ADCONx.

To enable digital input on RP0 you must set bit `PCFG0` in register `ANCON0`.

> BTW.. RP0 and RP1 represent pin 19 and 20 resp.. which is RB0 and RB1
>   normally..

Pins 19 and 20 on the PIC18F45J50 are RA0 (AN0) and RA1 (AN1).